# Getting a 302/"Page at xx displayed insecure content from xx" when attempting to upload images with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, http-status-code-302

Firebug gives the 302, and chromes throws the other message. Basically, I'm just trying to upload images with carrierwave and then I display the thumbnail  in my rails app. This works on demo and staging servers, but not on production for some reason. Any ideas as to why this may be?

```
<%= form_for Image.new, :html => {:multipart => true} do |g| %>
<%= g.text_field :whence, :id => "postWhence"%>
<%= g.file_field :image, :id => "postImage_file_field", multiple: true, name: "image[image]" %>
<%= g.file_field :image, :id =>"postLogo_file_field"%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using https in production?  If so, do the pages you are accessing serve any content via http instead of https?

This sounds like you have a https site serving content via http instead of https, which many modern browsers will detect as a security issue.

Comment: I've been able to confirm that this is indeed the source of my problem... now to try and find a solution. I tried changing the asset_host in the carrierwave  initializer to use https but that did not work.

Comment: Are any of your templates sourcing javascript or css from urls which may be https?  To reiterate, ANY content on the page which is loaded using http instead of https will likely trigger this failure.

Comment: The warning only appears when I attempt to upload an image though, which is why I think that's the root of the problem. In the console I get: Filter chain halted as :ensure_proper_protocol rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)"

With this form: (updated post to include)